# iPhone push-notification error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"

Tags: apple-push-notifications

All the setup as per requirements.

ApplePushNotification[7822:707]  Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x1922f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an error from push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457963/getting-an-error-from-push-notification)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the problem, its possible causes in order are below:

1. "produce CSR"
2. "download the development and production certificate"
3. "configure the development and production SSL "
4. "download the Provisioning certificate"