# APNS Error in registration. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Hello everyone i have beenn working in several projects and all push notification were working either on developemnt or prodcution. However i am not getting this error : "Error in registration. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000" since yesterday. I have tried to create a new provisioning but its shut down for maintenance. Is it due to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, searching this in Google would lead you to this [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457963/getting-an-error-from-push-notification

Comment: Thanks i waited for some time and regenerated the provisioning profiles.. its working again :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure the Bundle Identifier matches the one in your project's
   plist.
2. Create a new App ID, and configure it for production/development
   push before creating a new provisioning profile.
3. Make sure you're build and archiving on the right target, with the
   right configuration. You might need to go back to project settings
   and double check with the correct configuration selected (I use
   release for this).