# Does apns needs certificates for each app development?

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

I have created provisioning profile and app id and certificates & all of the process to enable push notification for one of my app, if I want to enable apns service for my second app shall I use same certificate or shall I create other provisioning profile and appid & certificates. I am using same certificates but I am getting following error.

> Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x1cd26cb0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

Even I am creating new certificate I am getting same error.where iam going wrong?i was struggling from few days help me

Comment: shall i need to crate another appid ssl and provisional profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siva, what matters for establishing an Apple Push Notification Service is:

- App Id
- Bundle Id of the app which is unique to each app.
- Provisioning profile [development/distribution] depends on your enviornment.
- Then the SSL certificates.

  So for your first question- you cannot use same certificates for two apps,which are having different bundle Id's. Because an SSL certificate is creating for a particular bundle Id. You can see that from your key chain.

  For the new app I would suggest you to create new Id, new bundle Id, new provisioning profile and offcourse new certificates. So there is no reason for any sought of confusions.

If the above mentioned error still prevails, you can refer these links- these are really worthy answers.
[How to fix "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" in Xcode 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987102/how-to-fix-no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application)

[Getting an error from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457963/getting-an-error-from-push-notification)

[no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432203/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application)

Comment: actually i have created app id in app store without enabling push notifications shall i modify it or shall i proceed with new id, also after creating certificates which certificate i supposed to add to my project is it .cer or provisioning profile

Comment: You should enable push notification for your app in the Apple developer portal.

Comment: k thank you and after which certificate shall i need to add to my project

Comment: If this is the first time you are implementing APNS, you should refer these tutorials:http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Or this:http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_apns/ This will give you a good idea of what is APNS and how to implement this..  From my personal experience, before using the actual server I implement APNS using Parse - https://www.parse.com/. They have an excellent tutorial and its very easy to use.

Comment: i was enabled for push notification under particular app id now my doubt is shall i create new provisioning profile

Comment: Yes, you should create new provisioning profile, when ever you make changes in the app.

Comment: k thank you when  the certificate expires what i supposed to do

Comment: still now iam getting same error any modifications in my project

Comment: If the certificate expires, you can create new one. Kindly check the links I have provided in the answer above.

Comment: my certificate is not expired

Comment: @siva please provide info on how did you resolved it, it is a hot topic and you could actually help others.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of certificate, Generate APNs key file.

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/add