# Same APNs for 2 different Apps

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, enterprise, mdm

I am developing an enterprise application for iOS.So in-order to release it through a particular MDM vendor, I've created APNs certificate through the apple site(https://identity.apple.com/pushcert), uploaded the same to the vendor portal and released the app successfully. 
Now if I want to release one more app using the same MDM vendor (to the same enterprise) means, do I need to create one more APNs or the existing APNs certificate that I've uploaded previously will work fine? 
Is it possible to have 2 apps under single vendor?
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found conclusion.
No need of having separate APNs certificate for each App you are releasing through Intune.We can upload/release multiple Apps using the same single APNs certificate.
It worked for me.I've successfully uploaded new App under the same APNs certificate.

Comment: How? Can you please share some knowledge?

Comment: As of I know the APNs certificate is for MDM vendor.Means the certificate has been associated between the device and
the MDM server. As MDM manages the device not the particular application, we can have single APNs for multiple applications.

Comment: Yes, But How can I set single APNs certificate to multiple APP ID in member center ??

Comment: In case of MDM , we are not creating APNs in member center, as we do for some other App store apps, instead we create APNs in Apple Push Certificates Portal [link](https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/).There it doesn't ask for APP ID, instead we just need to upload the .csr file provided by the MDM vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Here i'm considering Vendor as a new **"Market"**.If you are using same app ID for both vendors then existing APNS will work for you but if you have made a new app ID for 2nd vendor then you need to make new `APNS`.

Comment: No ,I want to release the app under same vendor, using same app ID.(only bundle ids will get differ).

Comment: if its different Bundle Ids' then it would be treated as different apps, and according the apple document, there's no way to use same APNS for different apps.

Comment: Here is a detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229276/does-apns-needs-certificates-for-each-app-development

Comment: For normal app if you are supporting push notification , we cant have two apps using same push certificate.But in case of MDM I am not sure whether we need different APNs for releasing different apps under same vendor, since I haven't specified bundle id anywhere while creating the certificate.

Comment: And also I didn't get your point above "If you are using same app ID for both vendors then existing APNS will work for you", do u mean to say the single APN will work for different vendor? If so, its not.To create APNs we need .csr file from vendor, so we can't use same APNs for different vendor, even if we are using same Apple ID.