# Bluemix - Push Notification Error

Tags: push, token, ibm-cloud

```
Error log:
Unable to receive push notification after configuring Bluemix Push Service.

Failed to get token from APNS, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain 
Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"
UserInfo=0x17595e20 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement 
string found for application}
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

This error means I am unable to receive notification from Bluemix.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Now I am unable to tell what your question is.

Comment: Can you post some more logs or what you are trying to do?

Comment: @user2450317 are you still having this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an error from push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457963/getting-an-error-from-push-notification)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following solutions which I found -
1. Generate a new provisioning profile, after you enable Push, and it should work

2. Make sure you use an app ID without a wildcard. Then you need to enable that app for push notifications for development. It may take couple of hours to start working
3. Make  sure in Built Settings, Code Signing Identity for debug is set to proper Provisioning Profile in which you enabled push notifications.

Source for further details:- [Getting an error from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457963/getting-an-error-from-push-notification)

Answer (score 1):

This seems a duplicate question asked already in stackoverflow:

[Getting an error from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457963/getting-an-error-from-push-notification)

You can use the solution provided in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your provisioning profile before configuring the app ID for push, try to regenerate the provisioning profile.

```
iOS Provisioning Portal -> Provisioning -> Your cert -> EDIT -> Make an edit -> Download new provisioning
```

it should work!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is following these steps :

Create .mobileprovision file before enable APNS.

1: Create App ID
2: Enable APNS
3: Then create Provision File

delete provisioning file from everywhere in your system(XCode,keychain,iTuneConnect). And then create provisioning file again.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you use an app ID without a wildcard. Then you need to enable that app for push notifications for development.

Below is getting started link for reference:

https://ameyashetti.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/apple-push-notification-service-tutorial/

Even after you've enabled your app id for push, it might take a couple of hours for it to work.