# Fail to register for remote push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I am getting the error in setting up the push notification on an iPhone 5 with iOS 8 :

> 2015-04-29 00:23:14.688 pushNotificationTest[192:6284] Did Fail to
>   Register for Remote Notifications 2015-04-29 00:23:14.698
>   pushNotificationTest[192:6284] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for
>   application" UserInfo=0x15e89820 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid
>   'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}, no valid
>   'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application Message
>   from debugger: failed to send the k packet

I use this link to implement it

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925

I already tried these work around provided by different people on this link :

[Getting an error from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457963/getting-an-error-from-push-notification)

code that i am using to register

```
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings=[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: Looks like you sign it with provisioning profile without push enabled

Comment: Did you set the APNS entitlement ?

Comment: what is APNS enitlement how can i use it

Comment: no it is enabled over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved it was just naming conflict between bundle and provisioning profile i make the names same after creating the new project

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in **Build Settings**, **Code Signing Identity** for debug is set to proper **Provisioning Profile**

in which you enabled push notification.

You don't have to delete or recreate anything. You just have to make Xcode update your active certificates (including the new push notification certificate).

**Simply go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > pick your Account > pick your Team > View Details**

There click the refresh button in the lower left corner. (Also check your code signing in build settings)

For creating certificate and provisioning profile follow this awesome [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: i have tried this after refreshing the profile it is still giving the same error i update the code the in the question as well that i am using it for registering the device

Comment: Have you tried making certificates using this tutorial? i will recommend you to try it.

Comment: i have resolved it was just naming conflict between bundle and provisioning profile i make the names same after creating the new project

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was "Push Notifications" option which was not activated in the "Capabilities" tab of my target.

Comment: Omg, thank you! Was creating all the time the certificates but did simply forget this

Answer (score 0):

Do you have push notifications enabled and configured for your App id? If you enabled them after creating the mobile provision, make sure you regenerate and download the mobileprovision again.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html) should help

Comment: i have already follow these steps to create the mobile provisioning profile but didn't help

Comment: i have resolved it was just naming conflict between bundle and provisioning profile i make the names same after creating the new project